# Adding directive, the binding will not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm new in Angular, I'm creating a mobile app with angularjs and ionic framework,
i have an input (project name) in which i have a directive, to verify if the project name already exists, that directive will disable the data binding.
Any help please.

```
 <input type="text" name="projectname" projectname-available    id="projectname" ng-minlength="3"
ng-maxlength="20" ng-pattern="projectPattern"  required   ng-model="form.projectname" >
<div class="error-container" ng-show="authorizationForm.projectname.$invalid && authorizationForm.projectname.$touched"  ng-messages="authorizationForm.projectname.$error"   ng-messages-include="templates/error-list.html">
            <div class="error" ng-message="required">
                <i class="ion-information-circled"></i>
                This field is invalid!
            </div>
            <div class="error" ng-if="authorizationForm.$error.projectnameExists" >
                <i class="ion-information-circled"></i>
                Project name exists already
            </div>

        </div>
```

this is the directive code

```
.directive('projectnameAvailable', function($timeout, $q,$cordovaSQLite) {
return {
 restrict: 'AE',
 require: 'ngModel',
 link: function(scope, elm, attr, model) {
   model.$asyncValidators.projectnameExists = function(projectName) {
     //here you should access the backend, to check if username exists
     //and return a promise
     query = "SELECT * FROM project WHERE name = ? ";
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, [projectName]).then(function(res1) {

            if(res1.rows.length>0) {
               exist = true;
               console.log('projet trouvé');
              }
            else
            {
            console.log('projet non trouvé');
             return exist = false;
             }
             }, function (err) {
                 console.error(JSON.stringify(err));
                }
             );
     var defer = $q.defer();
     $timeout(function(){
       model.$setValidity('projectnameExists', !exist);
       defer.resolve;
     }, 2000);
     return defer.promise;
   };
 }
}
```

});

Debug

```
 console.log('nom projet '+$scope.form.projectname );
```

i get  nom projet undefined

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/L18eeKqABZXu6BbgpMTv?p=preview)

Comment: please add a plnkr so people can see all in action and debug it.

Comment: this is the code in plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/L18eeKqABZXu6BbgpMTv?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were nearly there. Here is a working plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/qbAHG4dvDAHUOBzKbo5o?p=preview

I just changed one line in app.js from this:

```
defer.resolve;
```

to this:

```
defer.resolve(projectName);
```

Have fun.

Comment: it works, can you explain what is the relation between  model.$asyncValidators.projectnameExists and the input model? are they the same?

Comment: @tarekfellah good question. By adding the line: model.$asyncValidators.projectnameExists = function(...) {} you are defining a new validator called projectnameExists that gets bound to the model by way of the projectnameAvailable directive. You could repeat model.$asyncValidators.projectnameExists = function(...) {} multiple times with different validtor names if you had more than one validation rule. For example, if you wanted to also check if a project name is all lowercase and fail if not. You could use your directive to compound multiple validators and bind them all to the model.

Comment: so   model.$asyncValidators.projectnameExists will get the input model value and model.$setValidity('projectnameExists', !exist); sets the input validity?

Comment: Kinda, but there is a slight but important distinction to make. These are async validators so model.$asyncValidators.projectnameExists doesn't return a synchronous value like when you use a return statement with a string or a number. Instead, model.$asyncValidators.projectnameExists returns a promise immediately and that promise will eventually get resolved (because the operation is async). This is good because it makes sure that javascript's single thread doesn't lock up while it waits for the network or other async things to happen. The downside is the syntax can look confusing.